# Cast List<MyObject> to List<MyInterface>

Tags: java, class, list, interface, casting

I'm writing a piece of code in java and would like to encapsulate my object and only return interfaces.

Now in short this is my problem I have a class containing a list, and I have a getter which returns a List. How can I return a list of the interface ?

Without getting this error warning :

List is a raw type. References to generic type List should be parameterized

To give you a clear picture this piece of code is an example of my problem :

```
public class Employee{

  private List<MyObject> myObjects;

  public List<MyInterface> getMyObjects(){
    return myObjects;
  }

}
```

where MyObject implements MyInterface and return myObjects gives the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `return (MyInterface)myObjects;`

Answer (score 2):

If `MyObject` implements `MyInterface` you could change the return type to `List<? extends MyInterface>`.

```
class Employee{
  private List<MyObject> myObjects;

  public List<? extends MyInterface> getMyObjects(){
     return myObjects;
  }
}
```

Note that in this case the compiler won't allow you to call `add(...)` on the returned list, except you'd cast here. However, since you're returning interfaces only, I guess you're not planning to add anything to the returned list, so you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Simply declare a list of your interface as your instance variable.

```
private List<MyInterface> myObjects;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd simply define the instance attribute the way you need it:

```
public class Employee{

  private List<MyInterface> myObjects;

  public List<MyInterface> getMyObjects(){
    return myObjects;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though `MyObject` implements `MyInterface`, it is *not* true that `List<MyObject>` extends `List<MyInterface>` - see [this excellent document](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf) for more info. In order to inform the compiler of your intentions, specify the method signature like so:

```
public List<? extends MyInterface> getMyObjects{
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 
checkedCollection(Collection c, Class type)

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#checkedCollection(java.util.Collection, java.lang.Class)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast `List<MyObject>` to `List<MyInterface>`. So try to define `myObjects` as `List<MyInterface>` or use the following:

```
public class Employee{
  private List<MyObject> myObjects;

  public List<MyInterface> getMyObjects(){
    List<MyInterface> result = new ArrayList<MyInterface>(myObjects.size());
    result.addAll(result);
    return result;
  }
}
```